# Factorising AngularJS - How to properly use a factory to request and update data represent data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have been struggling to figure out the 'angular' way of working for using factories to represent ajax data (I do a lot of sharing between controllers using config). I have done some extensive research and all of the answers seem to fall in to two categories:

1. Use the factory to represent the data, then in the controller fetch the data and update the factory:

*{not intended to be actual runable angular}*

```
var app = angular.module('main', [])
app.factory('data', function($http){
    var data = []
    return data
})
app.controller('cntrl', [$scope, $http, data]){
    $scope.data = data
    $http.get('/data').success(
        function(idata){
            $scope.data = idata
    )
}
```

2. Use the factory to represent a http request with a promise and then assign that data to the $scope

   ```
   var app = angular.module('main', [])
   app.factory('data', function ($http, $q){
       var factory = {};
       factory.getdata = function(){
           var defer = $q.defer();
           $http.get('/data').success(function(idata) {
               defer.resolve(idata);
           })
           return defer.promise;
       }
       return factory;
   });
   app.controller('cntrl', [$scope, data]){
       $scope.data = []
       data.getdata().then(function(idata) { $scope.data = idata });
   }
   ```

I have several issues with this, in the first category the factory looks mega lame and like its not adding much value and each controller needs to have the code to manipulate the factory. With the second controller, the factory is very complicated and doesn't actually store the data (for sharing between controllers), just represents a long winded way to write a http.get

My question is this:
How can I use a factory to represent my data and manage the manipulation of that data in a clean way? What I would like to do is something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('main',[])
app.factory('data', function($http){
     var factory = {}
     factory.data = []
     factory.initialise = function(){
         $http.get('/data').success(
              function(data){
                   factory.data = data
              }
         )
     }
     return factory
})
app.controller('cntrlA', [$scope, data]) {
    $scope.data = data.data
    $data.initialise()
}
app.controller('cntrlB', [$scope, data]) {
    $scope.data = data.data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project with a similar issue.  What I ended up doing is using the service as a repository of the data.  Instead of the initialize function getting fresh data each time, it is getting fresh data only if the data repository is empty or a `getFresh` flag is tripped (manual override).  This way each controller can call the same function to get the data and manipulate it as the controller needs without tampering with the original data.

```
var app = angular.module('main',[])

app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q){
     var factory = {}
     factory.data = []
     factory.getFresh = false

     factory.initialise = function(){
         var deferred = $q.defer()
         if(factory.data.length===0 || factory.getFresh) {
             $http.get('/data').success(function(data){
                      factory.data = data
                      deferred.resolve(data)
             })
         }
         else{
             deferred.resolve(factory.data)
         }
         return deferred.promise
     }

     return factory
})

app.controller('cntrlA', [$scope, dataService]) {
    $scope.data = []
    dataService.initialise().then(function(data){
       $scope.data = data
    }
}

app.controller('cntrlB', [$scope, dataService]) {
    $scope.data = []
    dataService.initialise().then(function(data){
       $scope.data = data
    }
}
```